# Pass a string through jQuery AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX code that posts an ID to a PHP page, a year, and a semester, and at the success function. I console the data in order to see the JSON array but it only shows the JSON array when I don't put the semester into the AND clause of PHP. My code:

**AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#semester").change(function() {
        $("#year").change(function() {
            $('.searchBtn').click(function() {
                var id = this.id;
                var year = $("#year option:selected").val();
                var semester = $("#semester option:selected").val();

                console.log(id);
                console.log(semester);
                console.log(year);

                $.ajax({
                    traditional:true,
                    url: "getLoad.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data:{
                        id:id,
                        semester:semester,
                        year:year
                    },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#studentLoad").css("display","block");
                       // $("#courseCode").text(data.sem);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM stud_enrollment AS se JOIN subjectschedule AS s ON se.subjectscheduleid = s.subSchedID JOIN subject AS sub ON sub.subjectID = s.subjectid WHERE se.studentid = {$_POST['id']} AND s.academic_year_start = {$_POST['year']} AND s.semester = {$_POST['semester']}";
$retval = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Removing the semester from the AND clause will allow the data to appear in the console but adding it will do the opposite.

Comment: Just FYI, you should really look in to using prepared statements as your code is wide open to a lot of different attacks.

Comment: `$("#year option:selected").val()` is the same as `$("#year").val()`

Comment: Please update HTML Form

Answer (score 0):

As everybody said you should prepare your query, you can easily be being a victim of MYSQL Injection.

Have a look:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

and

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

The code seems fine, are you sure your dataset is correct? 
I mean, have you checked if exists a row which satisfies that criteria?

I'd re-write your query as per:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM stud_enrollment AS se JOIN subjectschedule AS s ON se.subjectscheduleid = s.subSchedID JOIN subject AS sub ON sub.subjectID = s.subjectid WHERE se.studentid = ? AND s.academic_year_start = ? AND s.semester = ?";


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

/* bind parameters */
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['id']);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['year']);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['semester']);

/*execute the query*/
$stmt->execute();

// Extract result set and loop rows
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($res = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = $res;
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

echo json_encode($data);
```